# Understanding c++ code; what do *datatype and classname::method mean?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C++ and I am trying to understand some code. What does it mean to have a * in front of the datatype ? and why is the class Name in front of the method name `CAStar::LinkChild`

```
void CAStar::LinkChild(_asNode *node, _asNode *temp)
{

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A * in front of the data type says that the variable is a pointer to the data type, in this case, a pointer to a node.  Instead of passing a copy of the entire "node" into the method, a memory address, or pointer, is passed in instead.  For details, see [Pointers in this C++ Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).
2. The class name in front of the method name specifies that this is defining a method of the `CAStar` class.  For details, see the [Tutorial pages for Classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).

Comment: Furthermore, you can think of it as a way of disambiguating function names. For example, say you have two classes (trivial example); one implements fractions (Fraction) and the other implements integers (Integer). Both classes may have a function called "add". By including the class name Fraction, the compiler will know that you are implementing the add function for the Fraction class, rather than the Integer class.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` means that it's a [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). You will also find that `_asNode *node` is equivalent to `_asNode* node`.

The class name is in front of the method name when the method is not defined inside the `class { ... }`. The `::` is the [scope operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Answer (score 2):

Are you new to programming in general, or just to C++?  If you're new to programming, you probably want to take some classes.  If you're just new to C++, you could try reading [Practical C++ Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004194/) an on-line [C++ Primer](http://www.hposoft.com/Programming/C++%20Primer.html).

Regarding your specific question: in the variable declaration, an asterisk means "this is a pointer":

```
int * pointer;
```

This also covers function declarations/prototypes, where the variables are declared,as in your example.

After the declaration, asterisk means that you're de-referencing the pointer.  That is, you're getting the value at the location to which it's pointing.

```
printf("memory address:%d value:%d", pointer, *pointer);
```

You'll note that memory address will change unexpectedly, depending upon the state of the program when it's printed.  In a simple program, you won't see the change, but in a complex program, you would.

Comment: I am new to C++. I've done work in mostly php, as3, and C#. but never in c++. But hearing these responses I am seeing that C++ is lil different. Like declaring methods outside of a class. But thanks for the info.